# Does LINQ return a deep copy of a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a variable called PeopleCollection of the `List<Person>` type

In the statement below, would newPeople get a deep copy of PeopleCollection ?

```
var newPeople=(from p in PeopleCollection select p).ToList();
```

Could any manipulation to newPeople affect PeopleCollection ?

Comment: Note that the select does nothing productive, you can just say `PeopleCollection.ToList()`.

Comment: Why ask when you can write an one-liner that tells you exactly what happens? http://ideone.com/IJkfyG

Comment: @Jon It is right he can check self, but this is almost true for all questions here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That will create a new list and add all of the items that were in that list to the new list.  It will perform a "shallow" copy of all of those items, so if those items are mutable reference types mutating them will be reflected from either collection.

This means that changes to either list itself (adding items, removing items, etc.) won't be reflected in the other list, even though mutations to any item in the list will be reflected from either collection.

(So in a word, no, it won't.)

Comment: SO if I modify the properties of an object in newPeople, that could affect the PeopleCollection variable?

Comment: @developer747 Well, technically no, you're not modifying the `PeopleCollection` *variable*.  The variable is just a reference to a list, and that list is just a bunch of references to people.  Changing It doesn't matter which list you use to find a person, there are no new people created as a result of the call to `ToList`.

Answer (score 3):

It returns a `List` that references the same objects returned by the `Enumerable`.